# Getting a "Connection closed by foreign host" error when hosting a TCP server on Heroku with Ruppell's Sockets addon

Tags: heroku, tcp

I'm trying to host a simple TCP server on Heroku.

I am using the [Ruppell's Sockets Heroku addon](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruppells-sockets#app-status-codes). My Procfile looks like this:

```
web: bundle exec ruby web.rb -e "production" -p $PORT
socket: ./lib/sockets-connect/rs-conn ruby ./tcpserver.rb
```

tcpserver.rb looks like this:

```
require 'eventmachine'

 module EchoServer
   def post_init
     puts "-- someone connected to the echo server!"
   end

   def receive_data data
     send_data ">>>you sent: #{data}"
     close_connection if data =~ /quit/i
   end

   def unbind
     puts "-- someone disconnected from the echo server!"
  end
end

EventMachine.run {
  EventMachine.start_server "127.0.0.1", ENV['RUPPELLS_SOCKETS_LOCAL_PORT'], EchoServer
}
```

`RUPPELLS_SOCKETS_FRONTEND_URI` is `tcp://22405.339f7303-45df-4e9c-a049-5a15c47168ab.sockets.ruppells.io:22405/`.

When I do `telnet tcp://22405.339f7303-45df-4e9c-a049-5a15c47168ab.sockets.ruppells.io 22405`, I get a `Connection closed by foreign host.`.

I have very little experience with TCP. Any idea how I can troubleshoot this?

Comment: Please note that Ruppell's Sockets is an alpha add-on and isn't open for everyone to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else struggling with this, your local server must bind to `0.0.0.0` and not `127.0.0.1`.